# S4 `.Data` slot does not work with tibble

Tags: r, tibble, r-s4

I set up a class `Test1` inherited from `tibble`. But I am confused when using `.Data` to initialize a instance from `Test1`.

```
library("tibble")

setOldClass(c("tbl_df"))

setClass(
  Class = "Test1",
  slots = c(dims = "numeric"),
  contains = "tbl_df"
)

test1 <- tibble(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])

## works, but with "star" in column names
new("Test1", test1, dims = c(5, 2))

Object of class "Test1"
# A tibble: 5 × 2
      a b    
* <int> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c    
4     4 d    
5     5 e    
Slot "dims":
[1] 5 2
```

It failed when I try to use `.Data`.

```
## error
try(new("Test1", .Data = test1, dims = c(5, 2)))

Object of class "Test1"
Error:
! Assigned data `map(.subset(x, unname), vectbl_set_names, NULL)` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 0 rows.
✖ Element 1 of assigned data has 5 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

A different error caused by using `.Data`.

```
setClass(
  Class = "Test2",
  slots = c(dims = "numeric"),
  contains = class(tibble())
)

## works
new("Test2", test1, dims = c(5, 2))

## error
new("Test2", .Data = test1, dims = c(5, 2))

Object of class "Test2"
[1] a b
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
Slot "dims":
[1] 5 2
```

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.21/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.21.dylib
LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2_1/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.0     purrr_1.0.1    
 [5] readr_2.1.3     tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.1.8    ggplot2_3.4.0  
 [9] tidyverse_1.3.2 pryr_0.1.6     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.10         cellranger_1.1.0    pillar_1.8.1       
 [4] compiler_4.2.2      dbplyr_2.3.0        tools_4.2.2        
 [7] timechange_0.2.0    lubridate_1.9.1     jsonlite_1.8.4     
[10] googledrive_2.0.0   lifecycle_1.0.3     gargle_1.3.0       
[13] gtable_0.3.1        pkgconfig_2.0.3     rlang_1.0.6        
[16] reprex_2.0.2        cli_3.6.0           DBI_1.1.3          
[19] haven_2.5.1         xml2_1.3.3          withr_2.5.0        
[22] httr_1.4.4          hms_1.1.2           generics_0.1.3     
[25] vctrs_0.5.2         fs_1.6.0            googlesheets4_1.0.1
[28] grid_4.2.2          tidyselect_1.2.0    glue_1.6.2         
[31] R6_2.5.1            fansi_1.0.4         readxl_1.4.1       
[34] tzdb_0.3.0          modelr_0.1.10       magrittr_2.0.3     
[37] ellipsis_0.3.2      backports_1.4.1     scales_1.2.1       
[40] codetools_0.2-18    rvest_1.0.3         assertthat_0.2.1   
[43] colorspace_2.1-0    utf8_1.2.3          stringi_1.7.12     
[46] munsell_0.5.0       broom_1.0.3         crayon_1.5.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original approach works fine. The appearance of `*` denotes a column of row names. It is only cosmetic, however, if you would like to get rid of it, you can try:

```r
library("tibble")

setClass(
    Class = "Test1",
    slots = c(dims = "numeric"),
    contains = c("tbl_df")
)

setMethod("initialize",
    signature(.Object = "Test1"),
    function (.Object, ..., dims = numeric(0)) 
    {
        .Object@dims <- dims
        `row.names<-`(callNextMethod(.Object, ...), NULL)
    }
)

# test drive
(test1 <- tibble(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5]))
(S4_test1 <- new("Test1", test1, dims = c(5, 2)))
```

**For a more detailed explanation**:

```r
library("tibble")

setClass(
    Class = "Test1",
    slots = c(dims = "numeric"),
    contains = c("tbl_df")
)

test1 <- tibble(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
S4_test1 <- new("Test1", test1, dims = c(5, 2))

S3Part_test1 <- S3Part(S4_test1, strictS3 = TRUE) # extract the S3 part from our S4 object  
identical(test1, S3Part_test1) # TRUE

.row_names_info(test1) # -5
.row_names_info(S3Part_test1) # 5
# so `test1` is not so identical to `S3Part_test1` after all
```

It seems that the call to `new` created an S4 object that does not have "automatic" row names in the underlining C data structures. My solution is creating a customized `initialize` to set `row.names` of the outputting S4 object to `NULL` so that automatic row names is set (See `?.row_names_info` and `?row.names` for more).

**Regarding the use of `.Data` in a call to `new`**: I think this practice should be avoid. The convention for calling `new` is that:

1. Unnamed arguments: objects of superclasses (i.e., classes in `contains` of `setClass`)
2. Named arguments: set S4 slots

Therefore, you original usage of `new` is fine

```r
new(
    "Test1", 
    test1, # unnamed argument is object of superclass (a tibble in this case)
    dims = c(5, 2) # named argument to set the `dims` slot of object of class `Test1`
)
```

messing around with `.Data` is unnecessary. Furthermore, your interpretation of `.Data` as a place to store S3 object is not correct, for example:

```r
A <- setClass("A", contains = "data.frame")
obj <- new("A", .Data = data.frame(a = c(2, 3, 4), b = c("A", "B", "C")))

> str(obj)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
Formal class 'A' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 4 slots
  ..@ .Data    :List of 2
  .. ..$ : num  2 3 4
  .. ..$ : chr  "A" "B" "C"
  ..@ names    : chr  "a" "b"
  ..@ row.names: int 
  ..@ .S3Class : chr "data.frame"

# notice that `obj` is malformed (0 observation)
```

A correct call should be:

```r
A <- setClass("A", contains = "data.frame")
obj <- new("A", data.frame(a = c(2, 3, 4), b = c("A", "B", "C")))

> str(obj)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
Formal class 'A' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 4 slots
  ..@ .Data    :List of 2
  .. ..$ : num  2 3 4
  .. ..$ : chr  "A" "B" "C"
  ..@ names    : chr  "a" "b"
  ..@ row.names: int  1 2 3
  ..@ .S3Class : chr "data.frame"
```

There are slots (`@names`, `@row.names`, `.S3Class`, ...) other than `@.Data` require to represent an S3 object.